# How to backup SQL data base with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

How can I make a SQL file with PHP that contains SQL script to create exact copy of my entire database. Like I can do it in PhpMyAdmin.

For example:

I have a database with few tabel and I would like PHP script to to return SQL script like:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `first_db`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure of table `my_table`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `naslov` text COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci NOT NULL,
  `besedilo` text COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci NOT NULL,
  `datum` text COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci NOT NULL,
  `avtor` text COLLATE utf8_slovenian_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovenian_ci;

--
-- Fill data for `my_table`
--

INSERT INTO `my_table` (`id`, `naslov`, `besedilo`, `datum`, `avtor`) VALUES
```

Comment: These are generated from the [`mysqldump`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) tool. You could do this with PHP alone, but it's not advisable.

Comment: I concur that it isn't advisable. For a large DB, the php script could time out before extracting the entire DB. It is best to use the proper tool such as mysqldump and the not to do it from the web application itself.

Answer (score 0):

just use exec() in php with the following shell command

```js
exec('mysqldump –u [user name] –p[password] [database name] > [dump file]');
```

dont forget that exec can be disabled in php.ini if it doesn't work

Comment: I would avoid running this due to the security risks... If for some reason you need to run a dump, run it via command line. If you need it run regularly, just execute the mysqldump from a cron.

Comment: It doesn't work. I deleted exec from "disable_functions" in php.ini. The code generate an empty file. 

I'm using Wndows 10, WAMP server; 
My data base settings: 
connection: localhost
user: root
password: 
database: first_db  

I'm a bit consernd when I leve blank space for password in the command